# Are fields defined in the END block in AWK?

Tags: bash, variables, awk, gawk

What would happen when using `$1`, `$2` ... in the `END` block, like:

```
awk '{print $3}END{print $1 $2}'
```

I found that `$1` and `$2` retain the values from the last record. Is this behaviour guaranteed by the standard or is it implementation-specific?

Comment: I would assume that it is implementation-specific. I don't seen anything in the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) that directly states that the field variables are *not* cleared in an `END` block.

Comment: I can't find a reference specifically to those fields, but many other variables, like `NR` for example, are specified to have the value of the last record processed, so it wouldn't be crazy to extend that to the field variables as well.

Comment: It is implementation-specific. See for example that in HP-UX `$0` is empty. [awk's END block behaviour on HP-UX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29970249/1983854)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND.html#I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND) we see that it is **implementation-specific**:

> Traditionally, due largely to implementation issues, $0 and NF were
>   undefined inside an END rule. The POSIX standard specifies that NF is
>   available in an END rule. It contains the number of fields from the
>   last input record. Most probably due to an oversight, the standard
>   does not say that $0 is also preserved, although logically one would
>   think that it should be. In fact, all of BWK awk, mawk, and gawk
>   preserve the value of $0 for use in END rules. **Be aware, however, that
>   some other implementations and many older versions of Unix awk do not**.

Comment: Correct. As @fedorqui pointed out in his comment [HP-UX awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970249/awks-end-block-behaviour-on-hp-ux), for example, is one that will not preserve `$0`, etc. in the `END` section. The workaround for the OPs script that I'd like someone with HP-UX to test would, I expect, be `awk '{print $3; last=$0} END{$0=last; print $1, $2}'`

Comment: @EdMorton that would be interesting to check, since I am curious to see if `$0` gets built in `END` as well. In my GNU awk it does `awk 'END {$0="a b c"; print $1}' file`, but this I don't know if occurs in all awk flavors.

Comment: It **should** work since POSIX says things like `assignment to $0 does blah blah blah`, not `assignment to $0 does blah blah blah except when done in the END section` but I'd like to get confirmation from a test with an awk that doesn't preserve `$0` into the `END` section.